# Problema con enlaces relativos en Scrapy

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

Quiero levantar las noticias completas de los enlaces que aparecen en la portada de un sitio informativo.  Pero los enlaces son relativos

El sitio es http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/

Y los enlaces se ven así

```
<div class="article-title">
            <a href="/v2/article.php?id=187222">Barros Schelotto: "No somos River y vamos a tratar de pasar a la final"</a>
        </div>
```

El enlace sería entonces, "/v2/article.php?id=187222"

Mi código es el siguiente:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.http.request import Request
try:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin # Python3.x
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urljoin # Python2.7

from puntalcomar.items import PuntalcomarItem


class PuntalComArSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'puntal.com.ar'
    allowed_domains = ['http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/']
    start_urls = ['http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/']

    rules = (
            Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(''),), callback="parse_url", follow=True),
        )

    def parse_url(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        urls = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="article-title"]/a/@href').extract()
        print 'enlace relativo ', urls
        for url in urls:
           urlfull = urljoin('http://www.puntal.com.ar',url)
           print 'enlace completo ', urlfull
           yield Request(urlfull, callback = self.parse_item)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        dates = hxs.xpath('//span[@class="date"]')
        title = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="title"]')
        subheader = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="subheader"]')
        body = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="body"]/p')
        items = []
        for date in dates:
            item =  PuntalcomarItem()
            item["date"] = date.xpath('text()').extract()
            item["title"] = title.xpath("text()").extract()
            item["subheader"] = subheader.xpath('text()').extract()
            item["body"] = body.xpath("text()").extract()
            items.append(item)
        return items
```

Pero no funciona.

Utilizo Linux Mint con Python 2.7.6

Salida por consola de scrapy:

```
$ scrapy crawl puntal.com.ar
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 1.1.0 started (bot: puntalcomar)
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'puntalcomar.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['puntalcomar.spiders'], 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'BOT_NAME': 'puntalcomar'}
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats']
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
['puntalcomar.pipelines.XmlExportPipeline']
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (404) <GET http://www.puntal.com.ar/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] DEBUG: Redirecting (301) to <GET http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/> from <GET http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2>
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/> (referer: None)
enlace relativo  [u'/v2/article.php?id=187334', u'/v2/article.php?id=187324', u'/v2/article.php?id=187321', u'/v2/article.php?id=187316', u'/v2/article.php?id=187335', u'/v2/article.php?id=187308', u'/v2/article.php?id=187314', u'/v2/article.php?id=187315', u'/v2/article.php?id=187317', u'/v2/article.php?id=187319', u'/v2/article.php?id=187310', u'/v2/article.php?id=187298', u'/v2/article.php?id=187300', u'/v2/article.php?id=187299', u'/v2/article.php?id=187306', u'/v2/article.php?id=187305']
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187334
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] DEBUG: Filtered offsite request to 'www.puntal.com.ar': <GET http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187334>
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187324
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187321
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187316
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187335
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187308
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187314
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187315
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187317
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187319
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187310
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187298
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187300
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187299
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187306
enlace completo  http://www.puntal.com.ar/v2/article.php?id=187305
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 660,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 3,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 50497,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/301': 1,
 'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 10, 16, 39, 15, 726952),
 'log_count/DEBUG': 4,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'offsite/domains': 1,
 'offsite/filtered': 16,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2016, 7, 10, 16, 39, 15, 121104)}
2016-07-10 13:39:15 [scrapy] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Solución:

Faltaba descomentar la configuración para solicitudes simultaneas en settings.py

```
# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16
```

**Moraleja:  'No des nada por sentado'**

Comment: Solución subida.  Muchas gracias a kikocorreoso por su tiempo.

Comment: Me alegro que funcione. Pero por aclararlo mejor, el problema entones no estába en el código *scrappy* que muestras. Cuando dices que "el código no funciona", tan sólo se trataba de que el *spider* de scrappy limitaba los accesos múltiples que hacías luego a la web.

Comment: Deberias quitar la solucion de la pregunta, responderte a ti mismo y aceptar tu respuesta. Así todo el mundo se enteraría.

Comment: O, quizás, por limpieza del sitio, se debería eliminar la pregunta completa ya que la pregunta inicial y la solución final no tienen mucha relación y cuando alguien busque por 'scrapy urls relativas' le llevará a esta pregunta sin solucion para ese problema.

Comment: Voto para cerrar esta pregunta porque no es un error no reproducible con lo planteado en la pregunta, y ésta y la solución final no tienen mucha relación y cuando alguien busque por 'scrapy urls relativas' le llevará a esta pregunta sin solucion para ese problema

Answer (score 1):

Con lo que expones no está claro donde está el error ni muestras el error completo. Entiendo que el error debe estar en el método `parse_url`. A ver si lo siguiente te funciona:

```
try:
    from urllib.parse import urljoin # Python3.x
except ImportError:
    from urlparse import urljoin # Python2.7

# ...

class PuntalComArSpider(CrawlSpider):
    # ...

    def parse_url(self, response):
        hxs = Selector(response)
        urls = hxs.xpath('//div[@class="article-title"]/a/@href').extract()
        for url in urls:
           #################################################
           # La siguiente línea está adaptada
           urlfull = urljoin('http://www.puntal.com.ar',url)
           #################################################
           yield Request(urlfull, callback = self.parse_item)
```

Si no te funciona, por favor, corrige tu pregunta para intar ser más claro sobre donde te está dando el error.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, kikocorreoso, pero ya había probado con urljoin() sin embargo no funcionó.  De todos modos lo volví a intentar con tu consejo y tampoco funcionó.

Comment: Corrigo y ccompleto el comentario anterior:  Gracias por tu respuesta, kikocorreoso, pero ya había probado con urljoin().  De todos modos lo volví a intentar con tu consejo, que es levemente distinto a lo que había probado antes y tampoco funcionó.  En la consola, scrapy no reporta ningún error.  Ni con urljoin() ni uniendo los strings.  Simplemente no funciona.  Saludos.

Comment: ¿Por qué no haces un `print(urls)` para ver si está pillando las urls de forma correcta? Ahora mismo, en el PC en el que estoy no puedo instalar cosas (trabajo).

Comment: Fijate que edité el código con tus recomendaciones y también agregué la salida por consola con los print().  Probé los enlaces completos y son correctos. También probé el script por cada enlace para ver si levanta los text y sí lo hace.   ¿Puede ser el HTML del stiio?  Realmente no se que ocurre.  Gracias nuevamente.